# How to "fix" flow types when you know from the logic that the type is correct?

Tags: javascript, option-type, flowtype

Well considering a function that takes/creates a maybe type (for say a number); Then another function that doesn't take this maybe type. To make it "work" I guard the function that doesn't take a maybe-type by adding a conditional around it.

A simple example:

```
/* @flow */

export function nullOrUndefined(val: mixed): boolean {
    return val === null || val === undefined;
}

function foo(x: ?number) {
  console.log(!nullOrUndefined(x) ? addOne(x) : null);
}


function addOne(x: number) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

The `nullOrUndefined` would be a generic guard, I created it to have a simple utility function that is expressive, so I don't have to constantly type the "complex" test in line.

The above functionality would work, and would not throw an error. (So long as `foo` receives a number, undefined or null.

However flow gives the following error:

```
8:   console.log(!nullOrUndefined(x) ? addOne(x) : null);
                                              ^ Cannot call `addOne` with `x` bound to `x` because null or undefined [1] is incompatible with number [2].
    References:
    7: function foo(x: ?number) {
                       ^ [1]
    12: function addOne(x: number) {
                           ^ [2]
```

[A small test](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcwoBXAOwGNCBLOcsc0mGAeXwFVyATDKG8hm4AKAG4BDGAC4wAWxpYhAShkAjOHBgZxDAN6owhsPgyFS+BhJhgAvHcbNrAHydgrt+xV79B3ANyoAL7oZFS09CQawlgyAPxMsqoY+Epg+oaU9ADOmhgAdPAA5sIAhEws7FzeAkLRqbFg4tzcrIJ1YDLlMEoBwSEU1HQMTS1tMQ6JyanpxqbmDFhgANRgAIy9QA)

I understand why this error occurs (flow can't look into any arbitrary function, and `nullOrUndefined` wouldn't even *be* in the same file.

But, how can I fix this? Other than `// $FlowFixMe` ? Or is this the case where explicit "ignore line" is correct usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, flow has first-class support for your case. Your error can be resolved by the addition of one token: `%checks`.

```
export function nullOrUndefined(val: mixed): boolean %checks {
  ...
```

[(try link)](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVxUgGwIHkoBVFAE2AUxWEoAoA3AQwIC44BbTEBgJRcARhAgFgrXAFI0AC2BoA1gGc4AbwBQcHXCjAYSKLjYE4AXkt5CZgD624pi1dTVa9SgG5NAX02bkdCwcRDFGEC4AfnxuYWAoAQ1tODQcFXFgADoCCABzRgBCfCJSCjc6BnDEyLhWSkpieiq4LmKCAW8-f0CMbFw6hqaI61j4xK0dfUNjOBA4AGo4AEZOoA)

`%checks` is used to indicate to flow that the indicated function is a [type refinement predicate](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-predicate-functions). Be advised, refinement in flow is pretty basic and will be very easily confused by a function basically any more complex than yours.

Comment: While this should work, it seems that this in practice fails when using the "type refinement predicate" across files (using es6 import system).

Comment: What is an example of a more complex type refinement that would fail?